# SSL issue: AWS Beanstalk with loadbalancer and external domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, load-balancing

I have a domain (example.com) hosted at 1and¹ and I have an AWS elastic beanstalk app for that domain. I am using an application load balancer and an SSL certificate from AWS certificate manager.

Ports 80 and 443 are open for the ec2 security group and also for the load balancer and the vpc. The load balancer is assigned to the SSL certificate on port 443. The SSL certificate is validated successfully for `example.com` and `*.example.com`.

1and1 does not have DNS record aliases. Thus, I can only point www (CNAME) to the load balancer but not the naked domain. For the naked domain, I therefore, use redirection to www.

Outcome:

`http://www.example.com` (works fine)

`http://example.com` (redirects to www.example.com and works fine)

`https://www.example.com` (works fine)

`https://example.com` (does not redirect to www and gives me an error when loading the page: Secure Connection failed)

So I am stuck with the naked domain and SSL - Why isn't it redirecting to https://www.example.com and how can I solve it while still using the DNS zone file at 1and1 and not Route 53? Thanks a lot for the hint!